# Entity Framework Core Migrations Preexisting Database InitialCreate Fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am attempting to use Entity Framework Core with a preexisting database, well sometimes.

To reproduce this error:

SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO

USE TestDB

CREATE TABLE Parent
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(400) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Child
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PARENT(Id) 
)

//CHANGE INSTANCE NAME IF NEEDED
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

This will create all of the models and context to access your database.

Now on to my issue.

I run `add-migration InitialCreate` and it generates a migration class. Great, right?

Then I run `Update-Database`

I get this error.

> There is already an object named 'Parent' in the database.

If I comment out everything in the up method the migration works.

How can I apply this migration on systems that don't have the database, but not on systems that have the initial database?

Comment: You might want to check if the tables exist before running the migration? An example in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531671/how-to-check-if-table-exists-in-a-migration

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an existing database and you have already ran
***Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models***
to get the models, you don't need to run or execute the following again:
***add-migration InitialCreate*** and ***Update-Database***
All you need to do is to make sure your connection string is correct.

Comment: you do not, however, if you want to add another table using code-first then you do.

Comment: Yes exactly. I agree