# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve user roles duplication in add-migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API I am running add-migration through this code:

Models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
} 

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Configurations:

```
public class ApplicationUserConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(name: "tbl_users");
        builder.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
        builder.HasIndex(u => u.UserName).IsUnique();
        builder.Ignore(u => u.AccessFailedCount);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.LockoutEnabled);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.LockoutEnd);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.EmailConfirmed);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.AccessFailedCount);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
        builder.Property(u => u.IsAdmin).HasDefaultValue(false);
        builder.Property(u => u.IsPasswordChanged).HasDefaultValue(false);
        builder.Property(u => u.IsDeleted).HasDefaultValue(false);
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole>
{

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationRole> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(name: "tbl_roles");
        builder.HasIndex(r => r.Name).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(r => r.IsActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserRoleConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole<string>>
{

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityUserRole<string>> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(name: "tbl_user_roles");
    }
}
```

Then I have the DBContext Interface:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
   public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
}
```

MyDBContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IMyDbContext
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime)
        : base(options)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        ConfigureDecimalPrecision(builder);
        ConfigureSoftDeleteFilter(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DDMDbContext).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Customize ASP.NET Identity models and override defaults
        // such as renaming ASP.NET Identity, changing key types etc.
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserRoleConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityRoleClaimConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserClaimConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserLoginConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserClaimConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationRoleConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserTokenConfigurations());
    }
}
```

I am using IdentitytDbContext. And I want to customize the names from AspNetUsers to tbl_users and AspNetRoles to tbl_roles.

When I run add-migration, I expected to see tbl_users and tbl_roles. Everything about tbl_users is okay. But for roles. I got both AspNetRoles and tbl_roles created in the migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "AspNetRoles",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "tbl_roles",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
            IsActive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: true, defaultValue: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_tbl_roles", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_tbl_roles_AspNetRoles_Id",
                column: x => x.Id,
                principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                principalColumn: "Id");
        });
}
```

And if I decide to update-database, it creates the two tables (AspNetRoles and tbl_roles).

How do I get this corrected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void Up() 
{
   if (!Exists("dbo.MyTable"))
   {
    ... do something
   }
}

private static bool Exists(string tableName)
{
   using (var context = new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
   {
    var count = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(OBJECT_ID(@p0, 'U'))", tableName);

    return count.Any() && count.First() > 0;
   }
}
```

reference link [How to check if table exists in a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531671/how-to-check-if-table-exists-in-a-migration)

Comment: It's like you don't understant the problem.  I want to have only tbl_roles for roles and not AspNetRoles. All the things in AspNetRoles should be in tbl_roles. And there should be nothing like AspNetRoles.